# How to Hide first three column in listviewitem c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am new in list view .

I am using this code to display data from a text file in a list view,

```
        int iRecords = 0;
        int iDate = 0;

        using (var sr = File.OpenText("C:\\test.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            bool flag = true;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] reader2 = line.Split(',');
                string Date = reader2[0];
                string rate = reader2[1];
                string Sym = reader2[2];
                double price = Convert.ToDouble(reader2[3]);
                double Sell = Convert.ToDouble(reader2[4]);
                double Buy = Convert.ToDouble(reader2[5]);

                ListViewItem lItem = listView1.Items.Insert(iRecords, Date.ToString());
                //lItem.SubItems.Add(Date.ToString());
                lItem.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;
                lItem.SubItems.Add(rate .ToString());
                lItem.SubItems.Add(Sym .ToString());
                lItem.SubItems.Add(Sell.ToString(), Color.White, Color.Red, lItem.Font);
                lItem.SubItems.Add(Buy .ToString()(), Color.Green, Color.Red, lItem.Font);
                iRecords++;
            }
        }
```

In this code ,it is displaying the date from a text file

For example

- Apple - 5 Min,9532,Buy,20100104,90500,5225,5232,5210,5219.7,469950,0
- Apple - 5 Min,9532,Sell,20100104,91000,5221.25,5225.9,5215,5221.7,387650,0

the first three arrays are same , they are * Apple - 5 Min,9532

I want to display the first line as it is ,
and the second line from sell, i want to hide the first three arrays in the second line

and later for Mange the same

- Mango - 5 Min,9532,Buy,20100104,90500,5225
- Mango - 5 Min,9532,Sell,20100104,91000,5221.25

I wanto to display something like this in a listview

- Mango - 5 Min,9532,Buy,20100104,90500,5225

  ```
               Sell,20100104,91000,5221.25
  ```

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This..

Set the width of the column/s you want to hide to 0.

Example:
lstVItem.Columns[0].Width = 0;

Comment: i dont want to hide the entire column in the listview i want to hide the first three arrays in the second line

Comment: You want to hide this "Mango - 5 Min,9532"?

Comment: ahmmm..why don't you try to replace the "Mango - 5 Min,9532," into ""?

Comment: cos you said that the first three arrays are same.

Comment: yes the first three arrays are same in the text file for every first 2 lines so i dont want to display it. i want to display the sell column down to the buy column